# Reading a JSON file and creating objects from it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class, object

I have a program that randomly generates 10 RPG characters. I have implemented the ability to save them to a `characterFile.json`, here is what is contained in that file:

```
[
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "da fu en ",
    "power": 30,
    "sAttackPwr": 60,
    "speed": 10,
    "type": "Elf"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "tuk ar da ",
    "power": 90,
    "sAttackPwr": 40,
    "speed": 50,
    "type": "Dragon"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "tuk el low ",
    "power": 30,
    "sAttackPwr": 60,
    "speed": 10,
    "type": "Elf"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "ant en ant ",
    "power": 90,
    "sAttackPwr": 40,
    "speed": 50,
    "type": "Dragon"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "tuk en el ",
    "power": 90,
    "sAttackPwr": 40,
    "speed": 50,
    "type": "Dragon"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "ar da ar ",
    "power": 90,
    "sAttackPwr": 40,
    "speed": 50,
    "type": "Dragon"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "kar ing tuk ",
    "power": 30,
    "sAttackPwr": 60,
    "speed": 10,
    "type": "Elf"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "da cha ing ",
    "power": 50,
    "sAttackPwr": 70,
    "speed": 30,
    "type": "Wizard"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "da cha low ",
    "power": 50,
    "sAttackPwr": 70,
    "speed": 30,
    "type": "Wizard"
},
{
    "health": 100,
    "name": "da cha tuk ",
    "power": 30,
    "sAttackPwr": 60,
    "speed": 10,
    "type": "Elf"
}
]
```

(The formatting when I paste it into SO is wrong, but how it is set out in the file is correct)

I would like to be able to read this back into the program, creating objects from that list.

This is what I have so far for the reading the file back into the program:

```
def openCharsToFile(gameChars):
    print("Loading File...")
    ans = input("Please ensure the file is called 'characterFile.json', then press [1]...")
    while True:
        if ans == "1":
            with open("characterFile.json") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)
                print(data)
                for x in data:
                    gameChars = characterClass(data[x][name], data[x][type], data[x][health], data[x][power], data[x][sAttackPwr], data[x][speed])

    break
```

`characterClass` is the class that I use to instantiate the object:

```
# Base Class for creating an RPG character
class character:
    # __init__ method, creates the name, type, health properties
    def __init__(self, charName, charType, charHealth):
        self.name = charName
        self.type = charType
        self.health = charHealth


class characterClass(character):
    def __init__(self, charName, charType, charHealth, charPower, charSAttackPwr, charSpeed):
        character.__init__(self, charName, charType, charHealth)
        self.power = charPower
        self.sAttackPwr = charSAttackPwr
        self.speed = charSpeed
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Now, I the way I understand this error is that I am trying to look for an index in a list, but am instead sending it the whole dictionary, which it can't turn into an Integer

What am I missing in order to use a loop to read this back into my program?

Comment: please provide traceback and 2 are you sure of `characterClass(data[x][name], ` shouldn't it be `characterClass(data[x]["name"], ` ... (note: you could pass as keyword arguments)

Comment: Please split your problem, so each part is easier to solve: One part is reading JSON and transforming it into an internal datastructure (nesting of dicts, lists etc.). The other part is converting that datastructure into instances of your character classes. Also note that in general this is called deserialization and that there are existing frameworks to facilitate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `x` is the actual character dict, not an index:

```
for x in data:
```

Try something like this instead:

```
for character in data:
    gameChars = characterClass(character['name'], character['type'], character['health'], character['power'], character['sAttackPwr'], character['speed'])
```

I also added missing quotes here, and I would recommend using a more descriptive name than `data`. How about `characters`? Python classes are normally named with `CamelCase`, so `Character` and `CharacterClass` might be better names than `character` and `characterClass`. Python's [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) might be helpful here.

Finally, I don't think you need that `break`.

Comment: Ah ha! Whilst this wasn't exactly was I was looking for, It got me round the mental stumbling block. I had to appened the list, as it is created empty:

`for character in ImportChars:
                    gameChars.append(characterClass(character['name'], character['type'], character['health'], character['power'], character['sAttackPwr'], character['speed']))`

Answer (score 0):

x is not the index but its the dict itself. For loop iterates over each entry loaded into data from JSON File. Correct code line should be:

`gameChars = characterClass(x['name'], x['type'], x['health'], x['power'], x['sAttackPwr'], x['speed'])`

Comment: How does this improve upon the answer that I gave 11 minutes earlier?